# How to simply authenticate a request in middleware?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, token, middleware, httpcontext

I am developing a Web API in ASP.NET Core 2.2. I want to authenticate every request by any user at any time based on token stored in Authorization header of HTTP Request so the user can call controllers and actions which are annotated with [AuthorizeAttribute]. This is my middleware:

```
public class TokenBasedAuthenticationMiddleware
    {
        private RequestDelegate nextDelegate;

        public TokenBasedAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) => nextDelegate = next;         

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IRegistrationsRepository registrationsRepository)
        {
            if (registrationsRepository.IsAuthorized(httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
            {
                //Code To Authenticate this request?
            }
            await nextDelegate.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

How can I simply authenticate the request (i.e set HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to true) without going into any complexity?

Answer (score 0):

You can  try something like :

```
var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", "YourName"), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "JWT");
httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
await nextDelegate.Invoke(httpContext);
```

But you can directly use the [AddJwtBearer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-2.2) extension if using JWT bearer token authentication . The `JwtBearer` middleware looks for tokens (JSON Web Tokens or JWTs) in the HTTP Authorization header of incoming requests. If a valid token is found, the request is authorized. You then add the [Authorize] attribute on your controllers or routes you want protected:

Related code samples :

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide

https://garywoodfine.com/asp-net-core-2-2-jwt-authentication-tutorial/

Comment: It sets the HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property to true, but if the the request is unauthorized, it throws the exception:   InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)

Comment: If the request is unauthorized, it will find the DefaultChallengeScheme to do the authentication , you didn't set that . You can directly return the unauthorized response in your `TokenBasedAuthenticationMiddleware` .